# Combining source code into a single file for optimization

Tags: c, optimization

I was aiming at reducing the size of the executable for my C project and I have tried all compiler/linker options, which have helped to some extent. My code consists of a lot of separate files. My question was whether combining all source code into a single file will help with optimization that I desire? I read somewhere that a compiler will optimize better if it finds all code in a single file in place of separate multiple files. Is that true?

Comment: GCC has an `-Os` option. Not that I've ever tried it.

Comment: The compiler may be able to inline some functions if they are all in one file.

Comment: If it is all in one file, then the compiler can more easily do 'dead' function elimination (remove uncalled functions) and may inline function calls, etc.  It will likely generate warnings as it does so.  Some compilers are moving towards 'whole program optimization'.  Check out [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (search term 'whole & program & optimization').  Google search 'whole program optimization' works well too.

Comment: -O3 is usually much smaller than -Os for my programs - ymmv

Comment: If you're using GCC you might want to experiment with the `-flto` option, which causes GCC to essentially store an intermediate form of the source code in the object files then re-run the compiler on the complete set of intermediate code during the link step.

Comment: Thanks! The -flto option was news to me and sounds worth a try.

Comment: If you're using VC++, look into whole program optimization and link time code generation.  It'll get the similar effect (compiler can do cross-compiland optimizations), while still leaving your code base maintainable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compiler can indeed optimize better when it finds *needed* code in the same compilable (*.c) file.  If your program is longer than 1000 lines or so, you'll probably regret putting all the code in one file, because doing so will make your program hard to maintain, but if shorter than 500 lines, you might try the one file, and see if it does not help.

The crucial consideration is how often code in one compilable file calls or otherwise uses objects (including functions) defined in another.  If there are few transfers of control across this boundary, then erasing the boundary will not help performance appreciably.  Therefore, when coding for performance, the key is to put tightly related code in the same file.

I like your question a great deal.  It is the right kind of question to ask, in my view; and, though the complete answer is not simple enough to treat fully in a Stackexchange answer, your pursuit of the answer will teach you much.  Though you may not yet realize it, your question really regards *linking,* a subject every advancing programmer eventually has to learn.  Your question regards symbol tables, inlining, the in-place construction of return values and several, other, subtle factors.

At any rate, if your program is shorter than 500 lines or so, then you have little to lose by trying the single-file approach.  If longer than 1000 lines, then a single file is not recommended.

Comment: You could always write `wholeprogram.c` as: `#include "source1.c" / #include "source2.c" / #include "source3.c" / ... / #include "sourceN.c"` to achieve both maintainability of separate source files and compilability as a single file for maximal optimization.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well, you can get away with that up to a certain point; it can end up taking a long time to compile, and use huge amounts of memory if the input is large enough (e.g. hundreds of thousands of lines). but yes, a good way to see the effects +1.

Comment: You can get a few hundred thousand lines into a single program on a modern machine with a few GiB of main memory without too much problem.  If your software is millions of lines long, then it is harder, but you could still build big chunks of the program in mega-object files.  I agree, though; it is not always possible.  There can be problems with the same name meaning different things in different parts of the project, for example.  Not clean coding, but that happens in multiple millions of lines of code developed over several decades.  So, clean code is a necessity for it to work.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes I thought about the same thing you've mentioned, but I have always been informed that including .c files is not a good option. Always wanted to know why, so anyone shedding light on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the compiler. The Intel C++ Composer XE for example can automatically optimize over multiple files (when building using `icc -fast *.c *.cpp` or `icl /fast *.c *.cpp`, for linux/windows respectively).

When you use Microsoft Visual Studio, or a derived product (like Atmel Studio for microcontrollers), every single source file is compiled on its own (i. e. one `cl`, `icl`, or `gcc` command is issued for every `c` and `cpp` file in the project). This means no optimization.

For microcontroller projects I sometimes have to put everything in a single file in order make it even fit in the limited flash memory on the controller. If your compiler/IDE does it like visual studio, you can use a trick: Select all the source files and make them not participate in the build process (but leave them in the project), then create a file (I always use `whole_program.c`, and `#include` every single source (i.e. non-header) file in it (note that including `c` files is frowned upon by many high level programmers, but sometimes, you have to do it the dirty way, and with microcontrollers, that's actually more often than not).

Comment: Is your second paragraph correct? Visual C++ does have [/GL (Whole Program Optimization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx) and [/LTCG (Link-time Code Generation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbf3tbeh.aspx) compiler/linker options.

Comment: @Blastfurnace It still compiles every file on its own. It has to - you can theoretically use different compiler switches for each file in visual studio. It's just that cl (the microsoft compiler) has this switch that chains another step of optimization *after* that. It doesn't work with gcc or icl. I haven't tested if it works as good with cl, as if it would when you use the "whole_program.c" method, but I guess cl will not have a significant difference there.

Answer (score 1):

My experience has been that with gnu/gcc the optimization is within the single file plus includes to create a single object.  With clang/llvm it is quite easy and I recommend, DO NOT optimize the clang step, use clang to get from C to bytecode, the use llvm-link to link all of your bytecode modules into one bytecode module, then you can optimize the whole project, all source files optimized together, the llc adds more optimization as it heads for the target.  Your best results are to tell clang using the something triple command line option what your ultimate target is.  For the gnu path to do the same thing either use includes to make one big file compiled to one object, or if there is a machine code level optimizer other than a few things the linker does, then that is where it would have to happen.  maybe gnu has an exposed ir file format, optimizer, and ir to target tool, but I think I would have seen that by now.

http://github.com/dwelch67  a number of my projects, although very simple programs, have llvm and gnu builds for the same source files, you can see where the llvm builds I make a binary from unoptimized bytecode and also optimized bytecode (llvm's optimizer has problems with small while loops and sometimes generates non-working code, a very quick check to see if it is you or them is to try the non-optimized llvm binary and the gnu binary to see if they all behave the same (you) or if only the optimized llvm doesnt work (them)).